# tree and logistic give different result

Tags: r, tree, glm

I am trying to analyse two independent variables(Say x1 and x2) influence on dependent variable(y binary var).
When I am using rpart or information gain, result shows that x1 is more important than x2. (split on x1 first and information.gain also larger)
While when I use glm on y~x1 + x2, the result shows x2 is very significant and x1 is not significant. Can anyone help me to explain the reason and which one I should use? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistical methods and interpretation, not programming and has been flagged for migration to Cross Validated.

Comment: once it gets migrated to CrossValidated, you might also want to consider editing the question to add a bit more information (e.g. results of `summary()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because trees and logistic regression follow different algorithms, it is entirely possible that they will give different results.

This usually implies that

1. `x1` and `x2` are correlated
2. Neither `x1` nor `x2` are good predictors of `y`.

If they are correlated, use PCA, or a similar technique, to reduce their correlation.  Otherwise, which one to use depends on your data.  You can use the training-testing set methodology to determine which gives a better fit and go with that model.

Just remember that trees are noisy.  A random forest (**randomForest** package) may be a better model.